# How can I populate fields in the active email?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a userform where the user checks off certain criteria. Depending on these criteria the To and CC are populated.

I want to populate the email currently active on Outlook.

I can get VBA to open a new email and populate the To and CC based on the checkboxes but I want to populate the open/selected email.

Comment: can you post your current code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but, if the form is available inside the mail item inspector you could make a call to the active mail item and reference the CC and Subject from there.

something along the lines of:

```
C#

Outlook.Inspector ins = this.Application.ActiveInspector();
Outlook.MailItem olMail = ins.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
olMail.Subject = subjectCriterea;
olMail.CC = CCCriterea;
```

Comment: The form is opened via a macro button on the ribbon if that helps

Comment: I see, I assumed you were working with VSTO. I made a similar thing last week, making a new task item from a Macro button. I only modified the open task with C#. Did you try adding the macro to the Mail inspector and then in VBA get the current mail item instead of creating a new one...?